# Tracking Equity Portfolio on Morningstar

Tags: portfolio, equity

I am tracking my equity portfoilio using morningstar.
However, roughly once a month my platform sells of some of my holdings to pay for platform fees.

How can I log this information into morningstar in such a way that the platform fees are taken from the overall calculation of my portfolio performance.

If I simply track these shares as being liquidated morningstar logs them as cash gained and not as a cost and so the calculation of my portfolio in morningstar looks inflated.